# Unable to find module './src' ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an ionic application. Which was working fine some months ago. But when I am trying to open it now. Its not working fine. In the meantime my Node has been updated to version 9. I am getting strange error for which I am unable to find solution anywhere yet. I face following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './src'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:542:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:472:25)
at Module.require (module.js:585:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/IonicProjects/ionic-app/node_modules/dotenv-webpack/index.js:9:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
```

What I have tried:

- Removed www/build and tried making build again using `ionic build`. It make build folder again but same error
- Updated npm packages, as appscripts was giving error that got  solved after updating

`ionic serve` works fine but showing blank page without any errors.

My ionic info is as follows:

```
cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.4.0 browser 5.0.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.4.2
```

System:

```
Node : v9.2.1
npm  : 5.5.1 
OS   : Linux 4.4
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Comment: I'm assuming your src file exists in the project correct?

Comment: Stop `ionic serve` and then try `ionic repair`

Comment: @StephenRomero yes its there.

Comment: @alex87 [ERROR] Unable to find command: repair

Comment: Try npm install

Comment: same error after running it

Comment: Try to install for dev-dependencies : 

npm install --save-dev dotenv-webpack

Comment: @ManojBhardwaj same problem after this also

Answer (score 0):

first remove your `node_modules`

```
rm -rf node_modules/
```

Then install again

```
npm install
```

After that

```
ionic serve
```

Comment: same error. ionic serve already completing successfully but showing blank page.

Comment: what is console log can you put it question

Comment: console log is empty.